# Fade out MOC if other application starts playing something

Tags: sound, alsa, music-player

I need to find a good way to force fade down the sound playback of a moc daemon

I have the following scenario:

I have running a small Ubuntu 12.04 server box with a MOC (musiconconsole) daemon and a custom ruby application.

The ruby application occasionally plays a wav or other soundfile in periodic or event driven scenarios. e.g. at 7 p.m. it plays "store_is_closing.mp3" or something like that.

I also have a MOC daemon running with a mp3 playlist, which plays music the whole day.

I am using ALSA to do the mixing.

Everything works fine but I am missing one point.

If, let's say MOC is playing a song and the ruby app plays a sound file, everything is on the same sound level (obviously). so, you can't understand anything of the sound file played by the ruby app.

I need to find a way to force the MOC daemon to fade down his playback of the song to a defined percentage (let's say 10% of the original sound level) and after the ruby app played the sound file, moc should be toggled back back to the origin sound level.

Comment: How are you mixing with ALSA? dmix?

Comment: alsamixer, i guess

Answer (score 0):

The MOC daemon can be controlled only with the `mocp` client.

If you were using PulseAudio, you could use `pacmd` to change MOC's volume.

If you replaced MOC with [MPD](http://www.musicpd.org/), you could use `mpc` to change MPD's volume.

If you really want to do this with ALSA, you could put the following into `/etc/asound.conf`:

```perl
pcm.moc_with_volume {
    type softvol
    slave.pcm "default"  # or whatever you're using in MOC
    control {
        name "MOC Playback Volume"
        count 1
    }
}
```

and configure MOC to use the ALSA device name `moc_with_volume` instead of `default`.

---

If your volume-changing program does not allow to configure its mixer control, you have to monitor the other mixer control and copy its value to the MOC mixer control. This could be done with a program like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

#define CHECK(fn) check((fn), #fn)
static void check(int err, const char *fn)
{
        if (err < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s failed: %s\n", fn, snd_strerror(err));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

int main()
{
        snd_ctl_t *ctl;
        snd_ctl_event_t *event;
        snd_ctl_elem_id_t *id_src, *id_dst;
        snd_ctl_elem_value_t *value;
        unsigned int mask;
        long raw, db;

        CHECK(snd_ctl_open(&ctl, "hw:0", 0));
        CHECK(snd_ctl_subscribe_events(ctl, 1));
        snd_ctl_event_alloca(&event);
        snd_ctl_elem_id_alloca(&id_src);
        snd_ctl_elem_id_alloca(&id_dst);
        snd_ctl_elem_value_alloca(&value);
        snd_ctl_elem_id_set_interface(id_dst, SND_CTL_ELEM_IFACE_MIXER);
        snd_ctl_elem_id_set_name(id_dst, "MOC Playback Volume");
        for (;;) {
                CHECK(snd_ctl_read(ctl, event));
                if (snd_ctl_event_get_type(event) != SND_CTL_EVENT_ELEM)
                        continue;
                mask = snd_ctl_event_elem_get_mask(event);
                if (mask == SND_CTL_EVENT_MASK_REMOVE ||
                    !(mask & SND_CTL_EVENT_MASK_VALUE) ||
                    strcmp(snd_ctl_event_elem_get_name(event),
                           "Some Mic Capture Volume"))
                        continue;
                snd_ctl_event_elem_get_id(event, id_src);
                snd_ctl_elem_value_set_id(value, id_src);
                CHECK(snd_ctl_elem_read(ctl, value));
                raw = snd_ctl_elem_value_get_integer(value, 0);
                CHECK(snd_ctl_convert_to_dB(ctl, id_src, raw, &db));
                CHECK(snd_ctl_convert_from_dB(ctl, id_dst, db, &raw, 0));
                snd_ctl_elem_value_set_id(value, id_dst);
                snd_ctl_elem_value_set_integer(value, 0, raw);
                snd_ctl_elem_value_set_integer(value, 1, raw);
                CHECK(snd_ctl_elem_write(ctl, value));
        }
}
```

(Use `amixer controls` to check the actual control names.)

Comment: thank you, but i have not the problem with the playback, i have a problem with simultanious playback. if MOC or MPD is playing a song  AND the ruby app is playing a sound file, i want the MOC/MPD playback fade down the sound level as long as the ruby app is playing the soundfile, then i want the music back to his origin sound level

Comment: Call `amixer`/`mpc` to reduce the MOC/MPD volume, then call the ruby app, then call `amixer`/`mpc` to raise the volume. If the ruby is running continuously, call the tool from there.

Comment: sry, didn't get it to work the way i wanted. darn. i guess i have to find another way. anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: Please edit your question to show how your Ruby app plays the sound.

Comment: i don't know how the ruby app plays the sound, it is written by another developer. i would be happy if i could create a virtual sound card which outputs the MOC sound to the INPUT (Mic) Channel of my physical card. this would be enough at the moment. i contacted the developer and he told me, that he will fix the ruby app to fade down the "Mic" channel on the physical card

Comment: Shouldn't that mixer control be configurable? (So that you point it at your MOC control?)

Comment: the question is where, which mixer control do you mean?
i created the enrties in asound.conf as you told me. Now, how can i tunnel the output from "moc_with_volume" to default.Mic ?

Comment: That entry will create a mixer control named "MOC Playback Volume".

Comment: wenn it doenst, i only have 1 Card and within this Card: "Master, PCM, Mic, MicBoost, SPDIF, SPDIF Def, SPDif 1, SPDif 6 and Capture"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11519/discussion-between-ello-and-cl)

Comment: You have to use the `moc_with_volume` device before the control is created.

Comment: well, thanks for you answers, but the problem is, the apps running are so designed that the fade down the "Mic" capture channel only. so i don't get moc to output it's music to the physical input of the soundcard, i have to find another way and can't use moc

Comment: Updated the answer.